# numpy: how to vectorize this nested loop

Tags: python-3.x, numpy, vectorization

I have to vectorize the following code:

```py
import numpy as np

data = np.array([
    [[5, 4], [1, 0]],
    [[7, 4], [0, 2]],
])

print(data.shape)

req_coordinates = np.array([
    [
        [[0, 1], [0, 1]],
        [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
    ],
    [
        [[0, 1], [0, 1]],
        [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
    ],
    [
        [[0, 1], [0, 1]],
        [[0, 1], [0, 1]]
    ]
])

print(req_coordinates.shape)

data_new = np.empty_like(data)
print(data_new.shape)

for i in range(data.shape[0]):
    for j in range(data.shape[1]):
        for k in range(data.shape[2]):
            #print(i, j, k)
            s = int(req_coordinates[0, i, j, k])
            t = int(req_coordinates[1, i, j, k])
            u = int(req_coordinates[2, i, j, k])
            #print(s, t, u)
            data_new[s, t, u] = data[i, j, k]

print(data)
```

Now, the code might look silly, but, do not go into the detail of what it is actually doing - the nested loops are part of a larger code; I merely extracted and assembled a working snippet.

I looked into [numpy.put](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.put.html), [numpy.vectorize](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.vectorize.html) but am unable to figure out how to go about writing the syntax for vectorizing the code.

Comment: `data_new[*req_coordinates] = data` I believe should work

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs you can't expand during slicing, you need to convert to `tuple` instead

Comment: It worked for me in repl (python 3.11.1) (numpy 1.24.1) @mozway

Comment: @Chrysophylaxs good to know, maybe a novel python feature, this fails in older python versions

Answer (score 1):

Convert your coordinates to tuple and assign to your empty `data_new`:

```
data_new = np.empty_like(data)
data_new[tuple(req_coordinates)] = data
```

output:

```
array([[[                  0, 1677574800000000000],
        [1677585600000000000, 1677589200000000000]],

       [[1677573000000000000, 1677576600000000000],
        [1677587400000000000,                   2]]])
```